# Where or how can I get list of domain dependencies of top 100 popular sites?

Tags: dns, domain

For example `google.com` depends on `ssl.gstatic.com`, `lh3.googleusercontent.com`, `fonts.gstatic.com`.

I need this list for Proxy settings

Comment: Could you please explain how did you determine that *`google.com* depend on `googleusercontent.com` and `gstatic.com`*?

Comment: @f-hauri If these 2 domains will be blocked, current version of google.com won't work properly

Answer (score 1):

#### About [dns](/questions/tagged/dns) [domain](/questions/tagged/domain) dependencies

*Domain dependencies* are only registrars. There is nothing else.

But you could ask for:

```
whois gstatistic.com | grep -A1 Holder
```

Hmm. nothing? Ok looking for names servers:

```
whois gstatic.com | grep Name.Server
   Name Server: NS1.GOOGLE.COM
   Name Server: NS2.GOOGLE.COM
   Name Server: NS3.GOOGLE.COM
   Name Server: NS4.GOOGLE.COM
```

and

```
whois googleusercontent.com | sed '/Name Server/q;d'
   Name Server: NS1.GOOGLE.COM
```

Also, building a proxy (meaning *web proxy*), is a *HTTP* concern. What you call *dependencies* are only web links to other repositories where to find some *objects*.

#### *Web domain dependencies*

Web pages depend on a lot of things:

- *scripts*: Libraries could be stored on development site
- *fonts*: Fonts are generally located on fonts servers.
- *styles*: Styles could be linked to scripts, stored on development servers.
- *videos*: Mostly located on stream servers.
- *map*: Geographic maps, stellar maps, oceanographic, human... And other specialised big data systems..
- *photos*, *images*, others...: Some copyrighted files could only be shown from original site (artist, photograf...),

But web domains **strongly** depends on

- *advertiser* where links to advertiser host is required for log count and further analisys.
- *captcha* [I hate captcha](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29571/is-there-a-true-alternative-to-using-captcha-images/29616#29616) but...
- *online banks* required for web shops.

#### Where to get such a list

On your web history, cache and mostly on the log of your proxy server...

Unfortunely such a list could not exist, because every web site could be build and modified at any time.

So if you plan to build a **strongly** restrictive proxy server, you have to keep some *hotline* up and stay ready to change your rules, adding some new 
kind of third party site, at any time.

#### And finally, about *Top 100 popular sites*

Answer could only be subjectives...

You could try:

- [duckduckgo.com](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=top%20100%20popular%20sites&t=hj&ia=web)
- [bing.com](http://www.bing.com/search?q=top+100+popular+sites)
- [google.com](https://www.google.ch/search?q=top+100+popular+sites)
- [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most_popular_websites)

... Then have a look at your proxy logs ;-)

#### Tip or trick:

Have a look at my answer about [How to display the Subject Alternative Name of a certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42489511/1765658),

Displaying *Subject Alternative Name* of SSL certificates give some *exhaustive* list of *directly related* domains.